# How to read HttpResponseMessage content as text

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm using HttpResponseMessage class as a response from an AJAX call which is returning JSON data from a service.  When I pause execution after the AJAX call comes back from the service, I see this class contains a Content property which is of type System.Net.Http.StreamContent.

If I inspect in the browser I see the network call being made successfully and the JSON data as the response.  I'm just wondering why I cannot see the returned JSON text from within Visual Studio?  I searched throughout this System.Net.Http.StreamContent object and see no data.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Send(HttpRequestMessage request) {
    var response = await this.HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you want to show us your code?

Comment: And what is it exactly that you want to do? Inspect the `response` variable?

Comment: yeah I was expecting to see JSON data that shows up as the response inside the chrome network panel to also be in that response object as it's content.

Comment: Open your immediate window and write `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`. If your return type is JSON, you should see it there.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The textual representation of the response is hidden in the [`Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.content(v=vs.118).aspx) property of the `HttpResponseMessage` class. Specifically, you get the response like this:

`response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();`

Like all modern *Async* methods, `ReadAsStringAsync` returns a `Task`. To get the result directly, use the `Result` property of the task:

`response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

Note that `Result` is blocking. You can also `await` `ReadAsStringAsync()`.

Answer (score 32):

You can use `ReadAsStringAsync` on the `Content`.

```
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Note that you usually should be using `await` - not `.Result`.

Answer (score 10):

You can you ReadAsStringAsync() method

```
var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

We need to use await because we are using ReadAsStringAsync() which return task.