# How to read validation error message when fail validation logic for passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-identity

In my IdentityConfig.cs

```
   manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = true,
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
        };
```

In my Web MVC UI, this is my action method

```
HttpResponseMessage responsePost = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Account/Register", registerBindingModel).Result;
        if (responsePost.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
                ViewBag.Message = "Added";
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Internal server Error: " + responsePost.ReasonPhrase;
        }
```

The code works. I can post data if it passes validation logic for passwords. But if it fails, it just throw back `Internal server Error: Bad Request` to my ui. But when I test it using Postman, I can see the error message from identity. Example `Passwords must have at least one lowercase ('a'-'z').`

Where this error message stored in `HttpResponseMessage`?

[image]

The API method for Register

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        return Ok();
    }

private IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            return InternalServerError();
        }

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            if (result.Errors != null)
            {
                foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                }
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                return BadRequest();
            }

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: HttpResponseMessage class has content property. You need to read value of that property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975001/how-to-read-httpresponsemessage-content-as-text

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya now I can read the error using `var content = responsePost.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                
                ViewBag.Message = "Error: " + content.Result;` But its output is `Error: {"$id":"1","Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"$id":"2","":["Passwords must have at least one lowercase ('a'-'z')."]}}`. How to I read just the `ModelState` error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the comments, you need to parse the string `content` which returns a `JSON` string assuming your `API` is designed in that manner.

I am not sure about your `API` code but if you need to send your `ModelState`, you can send it in JSON form using:

```
return Json(ModelState);
```

You should not use `IsSuccessStatusCode` for a way to check for your logic. Basically it is a value that indicates if the HTTP response was successful. It is `true` if HttpStatusCode was in the Successful range (200-299); otherwise `false`. The algorithm for `IsSuccessStatusCode` is shown below:

```
public bool IsSuccessStatusCode
{
    get { return ((int)statusCode >= 200) && ((int)statusCode <= 299); }
}
```

You can clearly see that the above function only depends on the `statusCode` received from the API.

Therefore you need to define your logic based on the `content` that you receive from the API. Create a model that will hold the response from the API based on the condition that you define in the API.

```
HttpResponseMessage responsePost = GlobalVariables.WebApiClient.PostAsJsonAsync("Account/Register", registerBindingModel).Result;
MyAPIResponse model=new MyAPIResponse();
string content=string.Empty;

    if (responsePost.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
      content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
      model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyAPIResponse>(content); 
      //or if you do not want a model structure for the parsing
      //var parsedmodel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);                   
    }

    ViewBag.Message=model.message;
```

I was not able to parse the content posted in your comment since it is not a valid `JSON` string. You would need to generate the correct `JSON` format for your logic.

EDIT:

So you can send the `ModelState` errors as JSON using a extension method:

```
public static class ModelStateHelper
{
    public static IEnumerable Errors(this ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        if (!modelState.IsValid)
        {
            return modelState.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key,
                kvp => kvp.Value.Errors
                                .Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray())
                                .Where(m => m.Value.Any());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then call that extension method from the `Controller` action:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    return Json(new { Errors = ModelState.Errors() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I think my error is in Json format. i have added error screen shot

Comment: @Steve Yes, the error format that you have mentioned in the comment is a incorrect `JSON` string.

Comment: Extra coded added in the original post. The error is added at `ModelState.AddModelError`.