# Convert HttpWebRequest to HttpClient with POST method

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, dotnet-httpclient

I try to convert HttpWebRequest to HttpClient but without success.
Can anybody help me?

It is my simple code with HttpWebRequest:

```
string url = "https://www.somesite.com/Service";
string postData = "text to send";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Proxy = null;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
request.ContentType = "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8";
request.Headers.Add("Cookie", SetCookie);//get it after login
using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()); 
string responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can convert you `HttpWebRequest` based code to `HttpClient` based like this:

```cs
string url = "https://www.somesite.com/Service";
string postData = "text to send";
var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
var content = new ByteArrayContent(data);

using var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies =  false, AllowAutoRedirect = false };
using var client = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("UserAgent","Mozilla/5.0");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("ContentType", "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=UTF-8");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", SetCookie);

using var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = content };

var response = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage);
var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Remarks:

1. Instead of writing the Request's Stream manually you can use the [ByteArrayContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.bytearraycontent?view=netcore-3.1) abstraction for this. ([Related SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971510/how-do-i-set-up-httpcontent-for-my-httpclient-postasync-second-parameter))
2. In order to set the cookie(s) manually you have to turn-off the default behaviour. You can do this via the [HttpClientHandler's UseCookies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.usecookies?view=netcore-3.1). ([Related SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373738/how-do-i-set-a-cookie-on-httpclients-httprequestmessage))
3. To set the headers manually you can use the [HttpClient's DefaultRequestHeaders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpclient.defaultrequestheaders) ([Related SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29801195/adding-headers-when-using-httpclient-getasync))
4. The counterpart of `GetResponse` is the [SendAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=netcore-3.1)
5. Instead of reading the Response's Stream manually you can use the [HttpContent's ReadAsStringAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=netcore-3.1) ([Related SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975001/how-to-read-httpresponsemessage-content-as-text))

---

*UPDATE*: Include OP's amended code

```cs
var content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "text/x-gwt-rpc");
```

So, instead of `ByteArrayContent` [StringContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent?view=netcore-3.1) is being used.

Comment: Becouse there was a poblem with header Content-Type, I had to change requestMessage.Content.
With this is ok: requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "text/x-gwt-rpc");

Comment: @Wojciech I've updated my answer to include your comment.